# Icy Manipulator vs Jayemdae Tome?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was watching this video of some old school magic: https://youtu.be/cEUBkHc36hE?t=911

During player A's untap phase, Player B used an [Icy Manipulator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIcy%20Manipulator%5d) to tap Player A's [Jayemdae Tome](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJayemdae%20Tome%5d).

I don't understand why this is effective. Why can't Player A use the Jayemdae Tome in response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Player A *could* use Jayemdae Tome in response.  But doing so limits their options.

If I counted correctly, Player A has 7 mana sources on the field.  That means that using Jayemdae Tome would use over half their mana.  This will severely cut down their options for what they can do in their turn.  Even if everything in their hand is cheap or useless, this is happening before Player A draws their card for the turn, so they could potentially draw something useful... and then be unable to play it.

Doing so would also shut Player A out of one or more colors, so even if they have enough mana to play the card they draw, they could easily have the wrong mana to do so.

This is especially important if Player A is using a lot of reactionary spells, such as instant speed removal and counterspells, because there's a lot of advantage to be gained by forcing your opponent to play around what you *might* have in your hand, and that advantage is lost if your opponent knows that you can't play any cards.

Of course, it's also possible that two players are not as strategically observant as they could be, and are just forgetting that that is an option.

Comment: A card like the tome is something you want to activate at the end of your opponent's turn. Especially with a blue deck.

Comment: @Arthur. More generally, best practice is to wait add long as you possibly can without wasting resources to take any action in the game, as that leaves you with the greatest possible options and gives your opponent the least amount of information. And "The end of the opponent's turn" Is very frequently the last possible moment before you lose access to that round's mana.

Comment: Thanks for the rules clarification. Later in the game (33 minute mark), the argument to be conservative with mana is pretty weak. Since at this point player A has at least 13 mana.

Answer (score 2):

**Most likely, the Tome player wanted to keep mana open for his pair of Counterspells.**

You are correct that the tome player could have responded to the Icy Manipulator activation with his own Tome activation. However, as you can see a few minutes later (only 2 turns per player have passed), the [camera pans around](https://youtu.be/cEUBkHc36hE?t=1212) to show the hand of the tome player, and we can clearly see 2 [Counterspell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCounterspell%5d)s. Using the tome would have meant he would be able to play only one of them, limiting his options. Drawing a card would have been reasonable, as it still leaves him with the option for 1 Counterspell, but he was taking no risks.